# How to check at compile time if a function is called

Tags: c++

I'm trying to identify at compile-time whether a function is ever called. Specifically, I want to throw a static assertion failure if it is:

```
template <typename T>
auto Function(T value) -> std::enable_if<someCondition, int>
{
  // this is the function I want to call
}

template <typename... T>
int Function(T...)
{
  // This function should never be called, instead I want
  // a compile-time failure if this is called, because it
  // means the above function wasn't successfully resolved.
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because failure to correctly call `Function()` with the correct conditions results in thousands of lines of compiler error messages, none of which are very helpful to anyone who is not intimately familiar with the code base.

The reason I don't want to place a `static_assert` in `Function` is because we have many of these functions, and we have the means instead to generate the `Catch-all` versions via macros, which would avoid unnecessary growth of the code-base while producing more helpful error messages.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand from your question why you don't want a `static_assert`. You do attempt to explain it, but I don't understand your explanation. If the catch-all versions are generated from macros, why can a `static_assert` not be generated from a macro too?

Comment: @Arman my comment has the intention to show that your title is a bogus.

Comment: @hvd no, because the macro is in a different location, and the `Function` that I do want to call is *not* generated by a macro. The reason I want to do it like this is because the macro (which is somewhere else) can still generate the catch-all function.

Comment: @40two ... yes but it failed. English is an ambiguous language!

Comment: @Arman Oh, I thought your question said you didn't want to have a `static_assert` in the catch-all function. My suggestion is to put a `static_assert` in the catch-all function. It's tough to refer to one of two function overloads by name. :)

Comment: @hvd ah right, no my question is basically *how* do I put the static assert there to cause it to trigger only if the function is actually called from somewhere. If I just put a `static_assert(false,...)` in there it'll just fail regardless, right?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. Why do you need the second function that should never be called? If you just remove it, you will automatically get a compile-time error if it would be called, wouldn't you? Isn't that what you actually wanted?

Comment: @Arman Right, that would fail. So don't do that. :) I've posted what does work as an answer.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen yes but I will get 50,000 lines of error messages that are almost impossible to comprehend to someone who doesn't know the code very well. I'm trying to create more useful error messages...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question, you don't want a `static_assert` here:

```
template <typename T>
auto Function(T value) -> std::enable_if<someCondition, int>
{
  // this is the function I want to call
}
```

...but there's actually nothing wrong with a `static_assert` *here*:

```
template <typename... T>
struct dependent_false { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template <typename... T>
int Function(T...)
{
  static_assert(dependent_false<T...>::value, "you are passing the wrong arguments!");
}
```

As you correctly noted, a simple `static_assert(false, "...");` would fail at template definition time. To get something that only fails at instantiation time, you need a dependent expression, and the `dependent_false` helper struct is an easy way to get something that will be type-dependent, will pretty much always be `false`, but cannot be assumed by the compiler to truly always be `false`: the compiler cannot rule out you adding partial specialisations to make `dependent_false<...>::value` `true` for some type.

---

Looking back at this old question, there may be a much simpler answer: mark the overload as deleted.

```
template <typename T>
auto Function(T value) -> std::enable_if<someCondition, int>
{
    // this is the function I want to call
}

template <typename... T>
int Function(T...) = delete;
```

This is not exactly the same thing, since this allows a caller to check the well-formedness of e.g. `Function(int, int)` instead of forcing an error, but it's more readable, and generally you *would* want that exact behaviour of not getting an error unless the function is actually used, not merely referenced.

Comment: Why not do `static_assert(false, "...")`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because that can (and typically does) fail at template definition time, instead of at template instantiation time.

Comment: Great answer, thanks :) It's a pity the STL doesn't provide `dependent_false`!

Comment: You can also just do something like ```static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(T), ...``` which saves a bit of code, but is a bit of a nasty hack.

Comment: @Riot That is not valid, technically. If there cannot be any valid instantiation of a template, the definition is invalid and compilers are allowed to reject it at definition time. You're making that hard, but not impossible.

Comment: Fair enough; it works on GCC, in any case.  If you can suggest a better test that works without extra lines of code, I'll switch to using that :)

Comment: @Riot There might be a standard library type template that *could* be used for this, but it would need to be one that can be used in an expression that returns `false` for *all* types, yet still allows the user to specialise the template for some type making the expression return `true`. Simple examples involving e.g. `std::integral_constant<T *, nullptr>::value` aren't valid, since the user is not allowed to specialise `std::integral_constant` to make `value` anything other than `nullptr`. Even if you do find such a type, I fear it would be such an unreadable mess that you should not use it.

Comment: @Riot Depending on the exact needs, it may be much simpler than I initially answered. Edited to give an alternative.

Comment: The disadvantage with simply marking it deleted is that it doesn't permit you to create a specific compiler error message, which is the whole strength of the static_assert case.  It would be nice to have something compact but that still allows this case.

Comment: @Riot Fair point. I'd probably stick with `dependent_false` in that case. If you prefer more compact but technically invalid code, then although I don't agree, I can understand where you're coming from.

Comment: What if the function that should not be called (e.g. an override of a pure virtual) is not a template function? Does this trick still work?

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend a bit on the accepted answer:
We can additionally define the following

```cpp
template <class... T>
inline constexpr bool dependant_false_v = dependant_false<T...>::value;
```

Usage is then:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
int Function(T...)
{
  static_assert(dependent_false_v<T...>, "you are passing the wrong arguments!");
}
```

Which looks more clean IMO and is shorter to write.

Using C++17, we can even get rid of the SFINAE `enable_if` and merge everything in just one function via `constexpr if`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto Function(T value)
{
  if constexpr(someCondition) {
    // Code for your function
  } else {
    static_assert(dependent_false_v<T>, "you are passing the wrong arguments!");
  }
}
```

Comment: My reason for posting this is as I got here following a Link in a blog about `constexpr if` which referred to the accepted answer in order to avoid the ill-formed `static_assert(false)`, see here: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr/